# How to sort this core data multithreading issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have an app where I am using core data to store messages and contacts, the app was randomly crashing with error

> Could not save. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={message=attempt to recursively call -save: on the context
>   aborted, stack trace=(    0   CoreData
>   0x00000001920eb02c  + 164   1   Pop
>   0x0000000100144528
>   TFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController10savePersonfCSo9CNContactT + 5808    2 
>   Pop                                 0x0000000100142af8
>   TFFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController27pullContactsFromAdreessBookFT8purgeOldSb_T_U_FTCSo9CNContactGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool__T
>   + 88  3   Pop                                 0x0000000100142b60 TTRXFo_oCSo9CNContactdGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool___XFdCb_dS_dGSpS1___ +
>   76    4   Contacts                            0x000000019886a898
>    + 144  5   Contacts
>   0x0000000198885588  + 96    6   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018fce1e24  + 132   7   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018fce1cb8  + 208   8   Contacts
>   0x000000019888545c  + 420   9   Contacts
>   0x000000019886a7fc  + 72    10  Pop
>   0x00000001001426f4
>   TFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController27pullContactsFromAdreessBookfT8purgeOldSb_T
>   + 1732    11  Pop                                 0x0000000100134790 TFFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController17reloadAddressBookFT_T_U_FT_T + 60
>     12  Pop                                 0x0000000100087f30
>   TTRXFo___XFdCb__ + 44     13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000101bb1a50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24  14 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bb1a10
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16     15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bc17dc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 980     16 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bc139c
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 140    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018eeb31d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1096     18 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018eeb2d7c start_wqthread
>   + 4 )}, [AnyHashable("stack trace"): <_NSCallStackArray 0x17464f2d0>( 0   CoreData                            0x00000001920eb02c 
>   + 164, 1   Pop                                 0x0000000100144528 TFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController10savePersonfCSo9CNContactT + 5808, 2 
>   Pop                                 0x0000000100142af8
>   TFFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController27pullContactsFromAdreessBookFT8purgeOldSb_T_U_FTCSo9CNContactGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool__T
>   + 88, 3   Pop                                 0x0000000100142b60 TTRXFo_oCSo9CNContactdGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool___XFdCb_dS_dGSpS1___ +
>   76, 4   Contacts                            0x000000019886a898
>    + 144, 5   Contacts
>   0x0000000198885588  + 96, 6   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018fce1e24  + 132, 7   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000018fce1cb8  + 208, 8   Contacts
>   0x000000019888545c  + 420, 9   Contacts
>   0x000000019886a7fc  + 72, 10  Pop
>   0x00000001001426f4
>   TFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController27pullContactsFromAdreessBookfT8purgeOldSb_T
>   + 1732, 11  Pop                                 0x0000000100134790 TFFC3Pop23PopMainScreenController17reloadAddressBookFT_T_U_FT_T + 60,
>   12  Pop                                 0x0000000100087f30
>   TTRXFo___XFdCb__ + 44, 13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000101bb1a50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24, 14 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bb1a10
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16, 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bc17dc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 980, 16 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101bc139c
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 140, 17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018eeb31d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1096, 18 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018eeb2d7c start_wqthread
>   + 4 ) , AnyHashable("message"): attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted]
>
> 2017-07-02 22:43:09.192263-0700 Pop[4552:2232120] [error] error:
>   Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data
>   change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet
>   addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null) CoreData:
>   error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core
>   Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of
>   NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet
>   addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null) 2017-07-02
>   22:43:09.192412-0700 Pop[4552:2232120] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet
>   addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18fdf2fd8 0x18e854538 0x18fdf2f20 0x18fd0f14c 0x1920ed268 0x1920ec230 0x1920e4f24 0x18fda09a0
>   0x18fd9e628 0x18fd9ea74 0x18fcced94 0x191738074 0x195f87130
>   0x1001031a0 0x18ecdd59c) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

So I enabled assertion to detect access to core data from wrong thread using com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

Now its showing assertion to every core data related operation.
Most of them I have resolved using newBackgroundContext and performBlockWait block.
But my question is why its assessing for every core data related operation ?

Comment: If you violate multithreading rules in core-data, then core-data may crash or misbehave at any time and in any way.  This means that you can violate thread safety once and 10 minutes later stuff can stop working.

Comment: I sorted this out but I am sure the thing for which it was asserting had nothing to do with threading , may be it's behaviour is a bit weird , I have read other threads too.